# Можно ли перемещать дочерние объекты в сцене из кода?

Tags: c#, unity3d

На объекте у меня находится grid layout group, хочу реализовать сортировку объектов по каким-нибудь параметрам (не важно) путём изменения порядка их расположения в сцене. Можно ли как-то перемещать дочерние объекты по индексу или как-нибудь ещё?
Может есть способ лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Дочерними являются не сами объекты, а координатные пространства

```
gameObject.transform.GetChild(int index); // Get childrenObject.transform
```